# Fetch Matching Subset from ArrayList

Tags: java, iterator

I have a `ArrayList`of some `POJO`. Let say Employee.

Then I am getting another `ArrayList` which contains only 'id' of that `POJO`.(i.e. Employee)

Now, I want a sub list of matching ids from my main list.

One way I can do it via iterating main list and comparing it with each id of another list.

But, I want to find out other optimum solution.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:**

- Sort the ArrayList of Employee (or a copy). Running time for this is `O(n*log n)`
- Find the first and last index of particular id. This takes `O(n)` running time
- Extract a sub-list using the start and end index. This also takes `O(n)`

Overall running time: O(n*log n)

Here is the whole procedure:

Initializing an Employee ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Employee> empArray = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

Creating some random Employees to test:

```
Employee empTemp = new Employee();
empTemp.setId("1");
empTemp.setName("emp1");
empArray.add(empTemp);

empTemp = new Employee();
empTemp.setId("2");
empTemp.setName("emp2");
empArray.add(empTemp);

empTemp = new Employee();
empTemp.setId("1");
empTemp.setName("emp3");
empArray.add(empTemp);

empTemp = new Employee();
empTemp.setId("4");
empTemp.setName("emp4");
empArray.add(empTemp);

empTemp = new Employee();
empTemp.setId("2");
empTemp.setName("emp5");
empArray.add(empTemp);
```

Sorting the Employees ArrayList w.r.t their IDs.

```
Collections.sort(empArray, new Comparator<Object>() {

    public int compare(Object obj0, Object obj1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Employee one = (Employee) obj0; 
        Employee two = (Employee) obj1;
        return one.getId().compareTo(two.getId());
    }
});
```

Initializing a temporary ArrayList of String which contains only IDs of Employees:

```
ArrayList<String> idOnly = new ArrayList<String>();
idOnly.add("1");
idOnly.add("3");
```

Here we create a new Employee Object and assign it the id we want to create a sub-list for:

```
empTemp = new Employee();
empTemp.setId(idOnly.get(1));
```

Find the start and end Index of that ID:

```
int start = empArray.indexOf(empTemp);
int end = empArray.lastIndexOf(empTemp);
```

Create a sub-list from the start and end index:

```
List<Employee> temp = null;
if (start != -1 && end != -1){
    temp = empArray.subList(start, end+1);
}
```

Only tweak is to `Override` the `equals(Object obj)` in Employee class:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Employee two = (Employee) obj; 
    return this.id.equals(two.getId());
}
```

I know its a bit tricky but it takes `n*log(n)` running time.

Answer (score 1):

Put the ids into a Set.  Then you can iterate over your list of Employees and test whether it is in the set you are looking for without a bad `O(n^2)` running time.

If you want to make prettier code, you could also look into [Maps.uniqueIndex](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#uniqueIndex%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) to build yourself a Map which you could then fetch out of.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway i have to iterate over collection. Optimum solution will be to use some library that can do this for you. Guava has [Predicate](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r13/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) which are realy helpfull in that case. Check the example:

```
//First we build a map that stores Id => Pojo pairs
Map<Integer, POJO> map = Maps.uniqueIndex(yourPojoList, new Function<POJO, Integer>() {
  public Integer apply(POJO pojo) {
    return pojo.getId();
}});
//Now we just intersect both set and your id's list
matchingIds = map.keySet().retainAll(new HashSet(youIdCollection)); //matchingIds is what you need
```

Answer (score 0):

What type has the id field? An approach could be that you insert the POJOs in the first ArrayList at a certain point of the array where the point is equals the id of the employee (this works only if it is an integer for example).

Of course this would mean that you are able to modify the insertion of the first ArrayList. Otherwise looping through the array is the only way I am aware of to solve that issue.